# How to get attribute from a <link tag in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.blogger.com/rsd.g?blogID=7487871339000666216" />
```

How can I get the href attribute of this link tag without using any javascript library?

Right now I'm using the code below to achieve this but I want to know whether there is a simpler solution.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
for (i in links){
    var title = links[i].getAttribute("title");
    if ( title == "RSD"){
        var href = links[i].getAttribute("href");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is more or less how to do it - except no need to do for-in since it is an array

Comment: @mplungjan `for`-`in` iteration is *not* appropriate, and `links' does *not* refer to an `Array` instance. It refers to an object implementing the `NodeList` interface, maybe even the `HTMLCollection` interface in some host environments (browsers). However, it would not be appropriate with an `Array` instance as well (see my answer).

Comment: That is what I said. Do not use for-in here. For all intents and purposes the collection will behave like an array. I cannot change my comment to say array-like.

Comment: @mplungjan Your correct recommendation was/is based on faulty reasoning. 1. A `NodeList` will *not* behave like an `Array` instance (please don't simply say "array", that is the *concept* instead); it is a *host* object instead. For example, `NodeList`s are live, `Array` instances are not. `NodeList`s have methods that `Array` instances are lacking. 2. AISB, `for`-`in` is inappropriate with *both* object types.

Comment: In my opinion this is pure semantics... Thanks for the lecture though. I will try to be more correct in the future.

Comment: @mplungjan `var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link"); console.log(links.length); links[0].parentNode.removeChild(links[0]); console.log(links.length); var x = {}, a = [x]; console.log(a.length); delete a[0]; console.log(a.length);` So much for "pure semantics".

Comment: Please show me a browser where `&& links.length` is needed in your code `for (var i = 0, len = links && links.length; i < len; ++i)` to extract the links. In this particular case, the user will never need to know the difference between array, nodelist/htmlcollection. Can we agree on this?

Comment: @mplungjan `&& links.length` in my code is needed with *all* implementations, so in *all* browsers. Omitting it would assign the value of `links` to `len`. That aside, the *developer* will need to know that they are dealing with a `NodeList` and not an `Array` as knowing that provides them with yet another incentive not to use the error-prone `in` operator here.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Modern browsers support [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) and [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelector("link[title=RSD]").getAttribute("href");
```

See [browser support chart](http://caniuse.com/queryselector).

Comment: Note that IE 7 and lower do not support this method. That said, I'd say "screw IE 7" and use `querySelector` anyway XD

Comment: @ShawnTaylor so where is your +1 ?

Comment: I tried querySelector before asking here but it did't work out...I must have done something stupid :( Thank you anyway!

Comment: @mplungjan: oops.. I mistaken.

Answer (score 8):

Original code:

```
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.blogger.com/rsd.g?blogID=7487871339000666216" />
```

…

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
for (i in links){
  var title = links[i].getAttribute("title");
  if ( title == "RSD"){
    var href = links[i].getAttribute("href");
    break;
  }
}
```

1. The markup above is [a `link` element, not a "link tag"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1).
2. There is no "javascript", [there are *several different* ECMAScript implementations.](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix) The term "javascript" is misleading and should not be used as an umbrella term for those programming languages.

   There cannot be "pure javascript" in a Web browser, which is a host environment. Even `document` refers to a *host*(-provided) *object*, which is not part of any core language ([ECMAScript Language Specification, 5.1 Edition [ECMA-262-5.1]](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), section 4).
3. Always declare your identifiers (`i` is undeclared).  Not declaring them, and thereby not attaching them to an execution context, has side-effects ranging from leaks into calling execution contexts to runtime errors.  Therefore, such code does not run in ECMAScript Ed. 5.x strict mode, it throws a `ReferenceError` exception (ECMA-262-5.1, sections 12.6.4 and 8.7.2).
4. Never use the `for`-`in` statement with array-like objects, in particular outside of testing not with *host* objects (`links` refers to one).  Neither consideration of only numeric property names nor iteration order is guaranteed (ECMA-262-5.1, section 12.6.4).
5. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself): Avoid accessing the same property twice (you are accessing `links[i]` twice). Else the result would be a greater variant in the program (the object may have changed in the meantime), and the approach would be inefficient and harder to maintain, unnecessarily.
6. Avoid calling the `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` methods of element objects in favor of accessing [attribute properties that have getters and setters](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-642250288).  The former are less backwards-compatible and known to be unreliable, in particular in MSHTML/IE where there is no proper distinction between attribute values and attribute property values.

   ```
   var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
   for (var i = 0, len = links && links.length; i < len; ++i)
   {
     var link = links[i];
     if (link.title == "RSD")
     {
       var href = link.href;
       break;
     }
   }
   ```
7. Use the `id` attribute and the `document.getElementById()` method if you want to refer an element quickly (but also consider using host-provided collections):

   ```
   <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD"
         href="http://www.blogger.com/rsd.g?blogID=7487871339000666216"
         id="mylink" />
   ```

   ...

   ```
   var link = document.getElementById("mylink");
   var href = link && link.href;
   ```
8. Do not use XHTML (syntax) unless you have to (remove the trailing slash if it is still Valid, see the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)).  With `LINK` elements in particular, which must be located within the `HEAD` element, it is a syntax error in HTML up to version 4.01 that has [no standardized remedy](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html).  [HTML5 specifies it](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-xhtml-syntax.html#the-xhtml-syntax) but that is still a Working Draft, and [not yet fully implemented in user agents](http://caniuse.com/#cats=HTML5).
9. People who satisfy themselves with saying only "screw $browser" have not had sufficient professional experience (see for example [The Internet Explorer 6 Countdown, by Microsoft](http://www.ie6countdown.com/), which is still showing a large number [currently 25.1%] of IE 6 users in emerging markets).  You would be well-advised to ignore the former group on this topic.

Comment: +1: adding details about the reasoning behind your suggestion would really help.

Comment: @ShawnTaylor [x] done.  Please ask if anything is still unclear.

Comment: +1 for detailed answer. "People who are satisfied with saying only "screw $browser" have not had sufficient professional experience" – I must disagree; when $browser is ~decade old, that's perfectly acceptable in most cases.

Comment: @jholster There is a difference between saying "I do not care" and "I do care, but not much". It is possible to emulate those features that are not yet supported, and degrade gracefully, with wrapper methods, achieving maximum compatibility with little effort. Any well-written script library should include such a compatibility layer, being optional if possible.

Comment: @PointedEars, no argument here.

Comment: @jholster The [CIA World Factbook for 2009](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/2153rank.html) (which may not be entirely accurate) says that there are 389'000'000 Internet users in China, and 61'338'000 Internet users in India. You have seen the IE 6 figures for China and India. In a global economy, can you afford to simply *ignore* more than 100'000'000 potential customers?

Comment: I think that's oversimplifying (for most business it's not realistic to consider every web user a "potential customer" unless you run Facebook/Youtube/etc) and hardly validates all the extra work (not talking about just adopting jQuery or similar), unless you are specifically targeting that audience. Besides, according to your numbers, 75% of them are already non-IE6 users! More importantly, browser usage statistics are not static, isolated numbers but there is a feedback loop between them and browser support provided by us (as webdevs).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8209/discussion-between-pointedears-and-jholster)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, by giving an ID tag.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lc7ut/

Answer (score -4):

You could use JQuery:

```
var url = $('link[rel=canonical]').attr("href");
```

Comment: Please look a title javascript pure is not jquery ;-)