# Access head elements from chrome.declarativeContent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that's active on pages with AMP versions, using a rule defined with the `chrome.declarativeContent` API. The problem I'm running into is that AMP links are stored in `head`, and the CSS selectors `PageStateMatcher` uses therefore won't find them. Is there a way to access `head` elements with this API, or do I need to use something more involved? For reference, here's the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-PageStateMatcher) I'm looking at, and here's my code:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function () {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [
        new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          css: ["link[rel~='amphtml']"]
        })
      ],
      actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug. Try reporting on https://crbug.com. Meanwhile you'll have to use a content script to check that selector explicitly.

Comment: In HTML, I would probably use [getAttribute() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) to fetch attributes like style, id, value, etc so this would be the closest option for me. Also refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441928/how-to-get-attribute-from-a-link-tag-in-pure-javascript) for additonal code implementation ideas.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, so I submitted a bug report [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=959320&can=2&q=declarativeContent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answers in the comments, I solved this by explicitly checking for the selector in a content script, then passing that to the background script like so:

```
var ampurl = document.querySelector("link[rel~=amphtml]").getAttribute("href");
if (ampurl.length > 0) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: ampurl});
}
```